# compare two columns having list of strings in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame in pandas having two columns where each row is a list of strings, how would it be possible to check if there is word match(es) in these two columns on a unique row(flag column is the desired output)

```
A                B            flag

hello,hi,bye     bye, also       1
but, as well     see, pandas     0
```

I have tried

```
df['A'].str.contains(df['B'])
```

but I got this error

```
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

Comment: Do you mean an actual Python list, or a string where the items are separated by commas?

Comment: What is `print (type(df.loc[0, 'A']))` ?

Comment: @BramVanroy it's not a python list, it's a series of words

Comment: @jezrael the output is <class 'str'>, btw your solution works. thanks a bunch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert each value to separately words by split and `set`s and check intersection by `&`, then convert values to boolean - empty sets are converted to `False`s and last convert it to `int`s - `Falses` are `0`s and `True`s are `1`s.

```
zipped = zip(df['A'], df['B'])
df['flag'] = [int(bool(set(a.split(',')) & set(b.split(',')))) for a, b in zipped]
print (df)
              A            B  flag
0  hello,hi,bye    bye,also     1
1   but,as well  see,pandas     0
```

Similar solution:

```
df['flag'] = np.array([set(a.split(',')) & set(b.split(',')) for a, b in zipped]).astype(bool).astype(int)
print (df)
              A            B  flag
0  hello,hi,bye    bye, also     1
1   but,as well  see, pandas     0
```

EDIT: There is possible some whitespaces before `,`, so add `map` with `str.strip` and also remove empty strings with `filter`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['hello,hi,bye', 'but,,,as well'], 
                   'B': ['bye ,,, also', 'see,,,pandas']})
print (df)

               A             B
0   hello,hi,bye  bye ,,, also
1  but,,,as well  see,,,pandas

zipped = zip(df['A'], df['B'])

def setify(x):
    return set(map(str.strip, filter(None, x.split(','))))

df['flag'] = [int(bool(setify(a) & setify(b))) for a, b in zipped]
print (df)
               A             B  flag
0   hello,hi,bye  bye ,,, also     1
1  but,,,as well  see,,,pandas     0
```

Comment: You probably need to `strip` as well to remove whitespace?

Comment: @jpp - yes, hard to know if problem of sample or real data.

Comment: @jpp where do I need to 'strip'?

Comment: @jezrael is the problem of real data

Comment: Ok, give me a sec.

Comment: @jezrael there is a small issue, if I have ,,bye,, in one column and hello,,,hi in another column, I get the flag as one ( as it should be zero)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174353/discussion-between-mostafa-alishahi-and-jezrael).